# How do you exclude a specific UIButton from an extension in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uikit

I am a beginner so bear with me.

I created a basic timer app and rounded the corners of two buttons. The button was still clickable outside of the circle, I needed to fix that so I found a solution online that said to insert the code into the UIButton's subclass or extension. I found solutions for both ways and chose extension option because the code was easier to read and I could understand it better.

The issue now is that I have a third UIButton that is being affected by the extension and I would like to exclude it. I'm not sure if this is even practical (or possible) so please correct me if there is a better way to approach this. The button I need to exclude from the extension is `resetButton`.

```
import UIKit

extension UIButton {
    open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        //exclude resetButton???
    }
    private var touchPath: UIBezierPath {return UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.bounds)}
    open override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return touchPath.contains(point)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!
    
    var timeRemaining: Int = 10
    var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        //// Moved to an extension in order to 
        //// remove the clickable areas outside
        //// of the circle
        //startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
        //stopButton.layer.cornerRadius  = 50.0
    }

    
    @IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(step), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
    
    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timeRemaining = 10
        label.text = "\(timeRemaining)"
    }
    
    @objc func step() {
        if timeRemaining > 0 {
            timeRemaining -= 1
        } else {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
        label.text = "\(timeRemaining)"
    }
    

}
```

Comment: "The issue now is that I have a third UIButton that is being affected by the extension and I would like to exclude it." In that case, an extension is a terrible idea for this. Create your own subclass of `UIButton`, and use the other solution you found.

Answer (score 2):

For your case, extension is not the right option as the methods invoked from extension will apply to the type itself (all `UIButton` objects in this case).

One option for you is to make a subclass of `UIButton` instead of extension. Something like this:

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {
  open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
      self.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
      self.layer.masksToBounds = true
  }
  private var touchPath: UIBezierPath {return UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.bounds)}
  open override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
      return touchPath.contains(point)
  }
}
```

And hence you can select the buttons that should inherit the custom layout from the class above:

```
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: RoundedButton!
@IBOutlet weak var stopButton: RoundedButton!
@IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton! // Will not get the style applied for startButton and stopButton
```